# Cannot add migration to project, result is 'Build failed'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to do a migration command with `dotnet ef migrations add InitialDB`, but the result is 'Build failed.'. Could this be a dependency issue? I had removed EntityFramework from the reference as I am told it is not compatible, however is there a specific version I should be using? I would like to know how to fix this issue? I am expecting it to create an InitialDB class file and should create regdbase in SqlServer.

**IdentityModel.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace UserWebAPI.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

    }
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="regConnString" connectionString="Data Source=cashamerica;Initial Catalog=regdbase;
         Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

**UserWebAPI.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" Version="2.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the build error?

Comment: I posted picture, check.

Comment: Have you check all your projects for remnants or dependencies on EntityFramework 6.1, because I see that being included in your build output. You need EntityFrameworkCore instead for a .net core application.

Comment: Ok I have new error 'No DbContext was found in assembly 'UserWebAPI'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.'

Comment: I need to know if there is an alternative reference for Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework ?

Comment: You need this instead: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/

Comment: On `base("DefaultConnection")`, I am getting an argument, "cannot convert from string to microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptions". I would like to know how to fix this?

Comment: I removed `throwIfV1Schema: false` because it does not take it in.

Comment: Ok, so I was reading this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2 and I was trying to figure out how to do it a different way and based on this article, it is a asp.net web app core. The one I am doing is not core, its just web app, and I noticed core has a startup class and the one I have does not. I think I would be better of using core because the connection string is in the startup.cs?